# Assign JavaScript var from Smarty in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to define a JS variable which gets it's value from a smarty variable..

This is what I've done in my PHP controller:

```
public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader()
{
  $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/bo_setup.js', 'all');
}
```

I'm declaring the variable on a separate function:

```
    private function _loadTestInfo()
    {
      $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
         'test_username' => 'myuser',
            ));
    }
```

and calling it from the getContent() function:

```
{
  $output = '';
 ....
$this->output .= $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/admin/back_office.tpl');
$this->_loadTestInfo();
$this->output .= $this->renderForm();
return $this->output;
}
```

my bo_setup.js function looks like this:

```
var test_username = "{$test_username}";
document.getElementById('username').value = test_username;
```

However, running the page gives the 'username' variable the value of "{$test_username}" instead of the "myuser" value.

any clues?

Comment: It's been a while since I used smarty, but it looks like you aren't processing your `bo_setup.js` file with smarty anywhere. Unless prestashop (which I've admittedly never used) automatically smarti-fies through the `addJS` function, I don't see how Smarty could operate on that file.

Answer (score 4):

For accessing variables in JavaScript you can assign them in your controllers with:

```
Media::addJsDef(array('mymodule' => array('test_username' => 'Your name')));
$this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'myscript.js')
```

Then you can use them in your JavaScript or through console:

```
let var1 = mymodule.test_username;
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be very late but the following should help you:

```
{addJsDef test_username=$test_username|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

This is to be added in the smarty .tpl file and it will define the variable for you.

After this, it might be good to ensure the javascript is executed once the content is loaded, using `document.onload = function ...` for instance.